# Still, un-bubbly cider after priming and left for 3 weeks at room temperature

Tags: carbonation, cider, priming, wild-yeast

This was the first time I primed my cider when bottling for carbonation. I exclusively wild ferment and press my own apples.

I added what I think was enough sugar (ca. 120 g for 25 L), and bottles were stored at room temperature (ca. 16ºC) for 3 weeks. Yesterday, I put one bottle in the fridge and left it overnight. I popped it open today and to my surprise, no bubbles.

What would you say is the reason for this? Is there not enough sugar, or should the cider be left for longer to carbonate?

Maybe the cider needs to be left in the cold for more than just night? I've heard that CO2 only gets transferred into the liquid at cold temperatures.

I use flip-top bottles and there's a bit of pressure released when opened. The still, uncarbonated cider is great as it is, but I would like to experiment with priming. Please let me know what your experiences are, and what would you do in my position :)

Share and learn!

Comment: 16°C is a bit cold for fermentation, it will slow it down for sure.

Answer (score 5):

Sound like its just not done yet.  Wild yeast will work slower than some purer strains will work. If there is pressure under the cap when you open it then there is some activity going.  Of course, if there wasn't enough sugar then maybe you've just got enough CO2 in the headspace.  I think more time will be needed.

The notion that the liquid only absorbs when its cold is not accurate.  Cold liquid absorb CO2 more readily and hold on to it more readily, but as the pressure builds CO2 will absorb even at room temperature.  So if your cider is flat despite there being a touch of hiss when you release the cap, I think it just needs more to to develop adequate pressure to start absorbing into the cider.

Answer (score 2):

It just needs more time.  Give it about 6 weeks, that should help.  Carbonation can take longer than you might have heard, and longer than you might think.

Keep it warm, don't chill it until you are ready to drink.  I agree with brewchez on that.